# Track attrition of an iOS app on firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

We are using firebase analytics in our iOS app.

I would like to find out number of new active users in a month and the attrition of our app monthly i.e., the number of
users leaving the app every month.

Attrition for a month(suppose January) can be calculated as

attrition = (monthly active users of January) - (monthly active users of January and February)

where (monthly active users of January and February) is the no of users that are active in January and also active in February.

Example: There are 100 monthly active users in January and 120 in February. The difference 20 can be interpreted either as 20 new users or as 40 new users and 20 left the app.

In the latter case the attrition can be calculated as

active users of January and February = 80 (20 left the app in January and rest of the users are
still active in February)

attrition = monthly active users of January - active users of January and February

= 100 - 80 = 20(the number of users who left the app)

The firebase console shows the number of monthly, weekly and daily active users. But it doesn't
let us filter users who are active in 2 different months.

So how to find the attrition and new active user count of our iOS app using firebase?

Answer (score 0):

Two options here:

1. Either [set a User Property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/properties#set_user_properties) as a month for which you want to refine the data for active users.

This option is not that great since Firebase restricts creation of 25 user properties and don't let delete them.

2. [Export Firebase data to Big Query](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765?hl=en&ref_topic=7029512) and [run query](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-firebase-analytics-big-query#querying_google_analytics_for_firebase_data_using_bigquery) to get the users (by setting a [userID](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.html#setUserId(java.lang.String))) for a month, typically done via DATE RANGE function.

Hope this helps!

Comment: When you export to BigQuery, does it include data that helps us determine whether they were active in a given month? Assume we haven't defined any custom events or properties.